# How can I combine the elements of mulitple lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is the code to start off with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import re

path = '/home/lhco/f1/*.cut'

files=glob.glob(path)

i=0
for i in range(len(files)):
    x = files[i]
    h = x
    i += 1
    f = open(h)
    for line in f:
            x = re.findall("([0-9\.[0-9][e][+-][0-9]+)",line)
            pb = map(float, x)

            if "ESC_00" in line: print pb
```

Right now, the output is 3 lists of numbers from 3 files in the directory. What I want to do is try to take each first element, second etc. from the first list and add it to the next lists' first element, second, etc. I tried to use map again on "pb" and the sum and zip but that did not seem to help much.
The initial output looks like:

```
[0.08]
[0.009]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.03]
[0.005]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.08]
[0.008]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
[0.0]
```

Is it possible to add the first elements of all the sets of 6 numbers to each other? Do I need to try something with tuple here?

File example:

```
0 EVENTS SURVIVE AUXILIARY CUTS WITH 0.000e+00 PB RESIDUAL CROSS SECTION

EVENT SELECTION EFFICIENCY IS 100.000 PERCENT

CUT_KEY SURVIVE PB_AREA %_LOCAL %_TALLY
ESC_001      38 2.3e-02 007.317 007.317
ESC_002       9 5.5e-03 076.316 078.049
ESC_003       0 0.0e+00 100.000 100.000
ESC_004       0 0.0e+00 000.000 100.000
ESC_005       0 0.0e+00 000.000 100.000
ESC_006       0 0.0e+00 000.000 100.000
```

Comment: If each line only has one number, as appears to be the case, then why are you using `re.findall` instead of `re.search`? You are overcomplicating things.

Comment: As a side note, `for i in range(len(files)):  x = files[i]...` is actually `for x in files: ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = []
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        result = []
        for line in file:
            match = map(float, re.findall("([0-9\.[0-9][e][+-][0-9]+)", line))
            result.extend(match)
    results.append(result)
answer = zip(*results)
```

This builds `result` lists for each file, and a `results` list of lists, then zips them to form the `answer`, which is a list of tuples:

```
>>> zip(*results)
[(0.08, 0.03, 0.08), 
 (0.009, 0.005, 0.008), 
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

Additionally, there is a typo in your regex (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8A6j5z/2)):

`([0-9\.[0-9][e][+-][0-9]+)` Parses to

`(  [0-9\.[0-9]  [e]  [+-]  [0-9]+  )`

when I think you wanted:

`(  [0-9]  \.  [0-9]  [e]  [+-]  [0-9]+  )`

which can be simplified to ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8A6j5z/3)):

```
\d\.\de[+-]\d+
```

Comment: I tried this and I seem to be only receiving the zeros from match, none of the other numbers.

Comment: can you provide better sample input? I had no issues replicating this with files with your example data.

Comment: `0 EVENTS SURVIVE AUXILIARY CUTS WITH 0.000e+00 PB RESIDUAL CROSS SECTION

EVENT SELECTION EFFICIENCY IS 100.000 PERCENT

CUT_KEY SURVIVE PB_AREA %_LOCAL %_TALLY
ESC_001      38 2.3e-02 007.317 007.317
ESC_002       9 5.5e-03 076.316 078.049
ESC_003       0 0.0e+00 100.000 100.000
ESC_004       0 0.0e+00 000.000 100.000
ESC_005       0 0.0e+00 000.000 100.000
ESC_006       0 0.0e+00 000.000 100.000`

Comment: It looks like the above but tabbed and spaced nicely, I didn't know how to format it in a comment.

Comment: @KeburFantahun just edit your original question to include it, preferably exactly as it would appear in the file.

Comment: @KeburFantahun I updated to include a fix for the regex.